# Error : The following classes are not declared even if their files have been loaded" after deploying sencha touch application

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.2

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < sencha-touch.js:8618
>
> Uncaught Error: The following classes are not declared even if their
>   files have been loaded: 'Ext.Title'. Please check the source code of
>   their corresponding files for possible typos: 'touch/src/Title.js
>       at Object.onFileLoaded (sencha-touch.js:8618)
>       at Object. (sencha-touch.js:3267)
>       at HTMLScriptElement.onLoadFn (sencha-touch.js:8275)

Answer (score 1):

The first error says that a certain file has been loaded but did not contain the expected JSON or JavaScript. Instead, the file contains HTML or XML.

The second error says that the file `touch/src/Title.js` does not contain `Ext.define('Ext.Title', ...)`.

These two errors occur in that succession if the following holds:

- your application somewhere uses `Ext.Title`,
- you didn't add `Ext.Title` to your requires section,
- the file `touch/src/Title.js` does not exist in the application directory and
- the web server delivering your application delivers an HTML error page if a file is not found.

Your application will try to load the file `touch/src/Title.js` only if the definition (`Ext.define('Ext.Title'`) is not compiled into app.js.

Usually, the underlying issue is that you are missing a `requires` directive in a file. The `requires` directives are evaluated at compile time and the components added to `app.js`, so your app won't try to load `Title.js` at runtime. If you add the requirement to the component that uses it:

```
Ext.define('MyOwnComponent',{
    requires: ['Ext.Title'], // <- add it here
    constructor: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.Title'); // <- if it is used e.g. here
    }
});
```

and compile your app again, you should be good to go. If you don't know where it is used, you can add it to your Application.js, which also has a requires section:

```
Ext.define('MyApplication',{
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',
    requires: ['Ext.Title'], // <- add it here
    stores:[],
    ...
});
```